# Topologically massive $p$-form gauge fields in arbitrary dimensions

Tags: field-theory, gauge-theory, chern-simons-theory

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$In $d=2p+1$ dimensions one can have topologically massive $p$-form abelian gauge fields $A\in\Omega^p(X_{2p+1})$ by considering a Maxwell–Chern–Simons action:
$$S[A] = \int_{X_{2p+1}} \frac{1}{2g^2}\d A\wedge\star\d A + i\frac{k}{2}A\wedge\d A. $$
In this case, it is easy to show that the gauge field has mass $g^2 |k|$.

In dimensions $d\neq 2p+1$ is there a similar way to gap $A$ out?

Of course, a Chern–Simons interaction does not make sense, but I was thinking something like a BF interaction, with appropriate form-degree fields. What is the correct treatment?

**Addendum:** Indeed, if we consider an action as
$$ S[A,B] = \int_{X_d} \frac{1}{2}\d A\wedge\star\d A+im B\wedge \d A + \frac{1}{2}\d B\wedge\star\d B,$$
where $A$ again $\in\Omega^{p}(X_d)$ and $B\in\Omega^{d-p-1}(X_d)$, we do get $A$ to be gapped, but at the cost of an extra gapped $B$. Can we somehow kill $B$? Also this works only whenever $d\geqslant p+1$. What about $d<p+1$?